# Should I use a base class for a method that adds user control to master page

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a method in a content page that does two things: it adds a user control to a placeholder on that page's master page, and it sets some properties of that user control. I would like to make this functionality available to all of my pages without repeating the code on the individual pages.

Would a base class be appropriate here? I have no experience with base classes. Would it be a base class for the master page? The content page? Some guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please post your relevant code and what you have tried.

Comment: Would a method in the master page not suffice? Why do you think you need a base class in the master page, considering you have no experience with base classes?

Comment: Check out the following: http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/master-pages/interacting-with-the-master-page-from-the-content-page-cs which says the following: _"In addition to defining the markup for the master page's ContentPlaceHolder controls, a content page can also assign values to its master page's public properties *and invoke its public methods*."_

Comment: Agree with Karl.  The Master Page's class is your base class.  No need to create another.

Comment: These comments are good answers. Why not post them as such?

Comment: The unwritten etiquette on SO is that if the answer is simple or more of a suggestion, it gets put in comments.  If it's a solution with code it belongs as an answer.  Of course, that's just what I've noticed in my time here.

Comment: That makes much more sense. Thanks for setting me straight.

Comment: The problem with that is that the question will never get closed. It will stay as an unanswered question forever.